# Problems with adding/removing ContentPanes in AccordionContainer

Tags: dojo

I'm a complete newbie at Dojo, and Adobe AIR, which is my target. I'm
trying to put some panes into an AccordionContainer like so:

```
var mainview = dijit.byId("mainview");
var rand = randomString();
var widg = gtd_create_entry_widget(rand)
air.trace(mainview);
air.trace(widg);
mainview.addChild(widg);
```

"mainview" is my AccordionContainer, and gtd_create_entry_widget() is:

```
function gtd_create_entry_widget(id) {

   var entry = new dijit.layout.ContentPane();
   entry.attr("id",id);
   entry.attr("title","title "+id);
   return entry;

}
```

The pane shows up in the container, with the correct id and title, and
no errors, however, if I try to add another pane, the next one shows
up too, but I get the error:

**TypeError: Result of expression '_7' [undefined] is not an object.**

I get the same error if I run

```
var mainview = dijit.byId("mainview");
mainview.destroyDescendants();
```

and also, only one pane is destroyed at a time, and I understand this
method should destroy all the children.

I can include full project code if required.

Thanks a lot

Garry

Comment: don't know if it's relevant, but make sure you call startup() on your accordion container if you created it programmatically.  To fully understand what's going on, a full example may be needed, and running against a non-optimized copy of Dojo will give you a more helpful error message.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure if this is going to fix your problem, but you're supposed to use dijit.layout.AccordianPane (http://www.dojotoolkit.org/api/dijit/layout/AccordionPane.html) with the AccordianContainer.